# Specific submatrix extraction in Python

Tags: python, matlab, matrix, indexing

it's a really simple problem, but I can't find any solution to it.

If I have a matrix

```
A = np.array([[1,2,4,2],[1,2,35,4],[3,4,7,0],[8,3,2,6]])
```

and I want to extract the submatrix made by the *first, second and fourth column* and *first second and fourth row*

In MATLAB I would do simply `A([1,2,4],[1,2,4])`, but I can't do that in Python.

Is there any fast way to do that? I need to avoid for loops since I'm working on a finite element code.

Comment: You can index directly ....

Comment: python is `0`-based indexing. So you would do `A[[0,1,3], [0,1,3]]`?

Comment: @DanielMesejo could you please be more precise?

Comment: @QuangHoang that's not a 0-based index problem... If I do that I don't get a matrix.

Comment: @DanielMesejo Yes I know. But If I do what Quang wrote in the comment, I obtain a simple array, instead of the desired submatrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution to your problem is `np.ix_`:

```
A[np.ix_([0,1,3], [0,1,3])]
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 2, 2],
       [1, 2, 4],
       [8, 3, 6]])
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! :)

Answer (score -1):

If you have a matrix like this

```
matrix = [
  [1, 2, 4, 2],
  [1, 2, 35, 4],
  [3, 4, 7, 0],
  [8, 3, 2, 6]
];
```

And you need recover the columns and rows cross, you want the result for:

```
    [1,2,4], [1,2,4]
    =>
    [
        [1:1 1:2 1:4]
        [2:1 2:2 2:4]
        [4:1 4:2 4:4]
    ]
```

This is a simple implementation.

```
def subMatrix(m, cols, rows):
  result = []
  for col in cols:
    newRow = []
    for row in rows:
      newRow.append(m[col-1][row-1])
    result.append(newRow)
  return result

subMatrix(m=matrix, cols=[1,2,4], rows=[1,2,4])
```